# VBA Excel paste data from other workbook row by row in transpose way

Tags: excel, vba

I have the data from various workbooks in the same directory, which I want to copy into my worksheet.
Unfortunately, it comes after every 5th row. In fact, I would like to start from row 5, but I want to have them placed row by row later on.

[image]

It happens to me with this code:

Sub CopyDataFromWorkbooks()

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim shTarget As Worksheet
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim strfile As String
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strPath As String

Set shTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CPP Summary")
strPath = GetPath

If Not strPath = vbNullString Then

strfile = Dir$(strPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

Do While Not strfile = vbNullString

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strfile)
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Info for CPP")

Call CopyData(shSource, shTarget)

 wbSource.Close False
 strfile = Dir$()
 Loop
 End If

 End Sub


 Sub CopyData(ByRef shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)

 Const VHead As String = "B1:B4"
Const VMBom As String = "B8:B25"

Dim glrow As Long

glrow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(5).Row

shSource.Range(VHead).Copy

With shTarget.Range("A" & glrow)
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End With
```

Is there any way to place these results row by row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the transpose on both special pastes like so:

`.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True`
`.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Transpose:=True`

Your code adapted would look like this then:

```
 Sub CopyData(ByRef shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)

    Const VHead As String = "B1:B4"
    Const VMBom As String = "B8:B25"
    
    Dim glrow As Long
    
    glrow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 'no need to offset per 5 now
    If glrow < 5 Then glrow = 5 'definitely starting at row 5 if there are no lines yet
    shSource.Range(VHead).Copy
    
    With shTarget.Range("A" & glrow)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Transpose:=True
    End With
End Sub
```